# How to validate one field against another with Yup?

Tags: reactjs, yup

I'm setting up a form with two fields; start month and end month.

Start month and end month are just represented by integers (0-11) for the corresponding months. I need validation to ensure that end month comes after start month (ie the integer for end month is bigger).

I've looked at other similar issues from a few years back, but yup seems to have updated to render them useless. I've tried the below code with a few variations.

I am also having difficulty validating end month as a number (`.number()` - I'm assuming I have to maybe to do this within the test function.

```
let schema = yup.object().shape({
  startMonth: yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .positive()
    .integer(),
  endMonth: Yup.string().test(
  "End Month Validation",
  "error message",
  value => {
    return value > startMonth;
  }
)
.number()
.required()
.positive()
.integer(),
});
```

> Errors:
>   Line 102:  'startMonth' is not defined  no-undef

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another approach would be to make use of [`.ref()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#yuprefpath-string-options--contextprefix-string--ref) and [`.moreThan()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#numbermorethanmin-number--ref-message-string--function-schema) to perform this validation logic.

Something like the following should achieve what you require:

```
let schema = Yup.object().shape({
  startMonth: Yup
    .number()
    .required()
    .positive()
    .integer(),
  endMonth: Yup.number() /* Remove .string() */
    .required()
    .positive()
    /* Reference startMonth field in validating endMonth value */
    .moreThan(Yup.ref('startMonth'), "End month must come after start month")
    .integer(),
});

schema.validate({ startMonth : 1, endMonth : 2 })  // Okay!
schema.validate({ startMonth : 11, endMonth : 2 }) // Throws exception
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: That codepen link seems to be the wrong one. Would you kindly post the right one if you still have it somewhere?

Comment: @RaymondWachaga you're right - it is the wrong link. My apologies about that. Unfortunately I don't have the correct link anymore. Is there something I can help you with in particular?

Comment: It's all good now. I resolved the issue I was having. I thought it was an issue with Yup but it was how I was handling the validation.